# Same shadow for android and ios

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I know there is `elevation` for android and `shadowColor`, `shadowOffset`, `shadowOpacity`, `shadowRadius` for ios. But I want to get the same shadow for android and ios, but i can't do it with just `elevation` for android.
So, i tested the packages `react-native-shadow` and `react-native-shadow-2`, they are not too bad, but they have so many default:

`react-native-shadow`:

- is old
- can not have child size
- too many options for nothing
- ...

`react-native-shadow-2`:

- supports the dynamic size (`width='100%'`).. but the child of `Shadow` can't fill the parent size by setting `width='100%'` or with the `height` ...
- can not define the intensity of the blur (it is automatic)
- ...

How or what can I do for get the same shadow like I can do it with ios for android (like, with approximately the same properties for ios) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am the dev of the react-native-shadow-2 :)

For the "but the child of Shadow can't fill the parent size by setting width='100%'", I have recently added to the FAQ this issue:

> Q: My component is no longer using the available parent width after
> applying the Shadow! What to do?
>
> A: Use viewStyle={{alignSelf: 'stretch'}} or undefined instead of
> 'stretch', in your Shadow component.

Feel free to open any issue in the [repository](https://github.com/SrBrahma/react-native-shadow-2)!